# How to store only the users response when using the Azure chat bot

Tags: c#, azure, botframework, azure-table-storage, chatbot

I am trying to store the users response in a table storage. I only want to store the users data they enter, and am not interested in the bots response. 
How is this possible and additionally would this be possible on a trigger word, for example when the user says "no" it logs there first interaction with the bot for example "Hello".

I have done lots of research on this subject but storing only the users input seems to be less documented.

Any help with this would be much appreciated!

Comment: `How is this possible and additionally would this be possible on a trigger word, for example when the user says "no" it logs there first interaction with the bot for example "Hello".` Can you clarify more about this requirement?

Comment: When the user types the word "No", their first message they send will be stored. For example: 

Hello im the chat bot how can I help you

          My PC does not work    -- First Message

Turn it off and on again, did this help?

          No    --Trigger

@FeiHan Did this help clarify?

Comment: `When the user types the word "No", their first message they send will be stored.` Hi @L.Full, based on your requirement, I shared a reply, please refer to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am trying to store the users response in a table storage. I only want to store the users data they enter, and am not interested in the bots response. How is this possible and additionally would this be possible on a trigger word, for example when the user says "no" it logs there first interaction with the bot for example "Hello".

It seems that you just want to store user inputs in table storage, not store data of bot’s response. To achieve the requirement, you can intercept message that user send in `MessagesController` (or in dialog `MessageReceivedAsync` method), and then extract properties values that you want from `activity` and store values in your table storage.

```
public static string firstmessage = null;

/// <summary>
/// POST: api/Messages
/// Receive a message from a user and reply to it
/// </summary>
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        if (firstmessage == null)
        {
            firstmessage = activity.Text?.ToString();
        }

        storeuserinput(activity);

        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());

    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}

private void storeuserinput(Activity activity)
{
    var uid = activity.From.Id;
    var uname = activity.From.Name;

    if (activity.Text?.ToLower().ToString() == "no")
    {
        var userinput = firstmessage;
    }

    //extract other data from "activity" object

    //your code logic here
    //store data in your table storage

    //Note: specifcial scenario of user send attachment
}
```

And If you’d like to store data into Azure table storage, you can use [WindowsAzure.Storage client library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage) to store/add entities to a table.

Besides, [the middleware functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-middleware?view=azure-bot-service-3.0) in the Bot Builder SDK enables us to intercept all messages that are exchanged between user and bot, you can refer to the following code snippet to achieve same requirement.

```
public class MyActivityLogger : IActivityLogger
{
    public async Task LogAsync(IActivity activity)
    {
        if (activity.From.Name!= "{your_botid_here}")
        {
            var uid = activity.From.Id;
            var uname = activity.From.Name;

            var userinput = (activity as IMessageActivity).Text?.ToString();

            //extract other data from "activity" properties

            //your code logic here
            //store data in your table storage

            //Note: specifcial scenario of user send attachment

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, how would I go about putting this into my Azure table storage? @FeiHan

Comment: As in loading the userinput  variable into the table storage

Comment: `how would I go about putting this into my Azure table storage?` You can refer to [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table-storage-how-to-use-dotnet#add-an-entity-to-a-table) to add it as an entity to your table.

Comment: How could this be applied to use the bots response as a trigger instead?